# Mongodb aggregate query with retrieval with two keys and condition by another variable

Tags: mongodb

Hi i'm really quite bad at aggregation so need some help here.

I have a table schema with attributes below:

- shareId (string), represents a video post
- value (integer), the duration for which a user watches the video
- userId (string), the userId

I need to retrieve the highest duration by the user for each video. In this case, a unique combination of shareId + userId (which represents a user watching a share) and retrieval of the highest value.

Here is a sample. In this example, i only want the 2nd row (1/2/5) and not the first. (The first is considered a duplication for me)

*EDIT. Note i do not have the specific shareId and userId. In fact, i need to retrieve all the shares/users on this table in this fashion, but where there is a duplicate shareId / userId - to only return the one with the highest value.

[image]

One thing to note, the table has tens and thousands of records so i do need it to be optimized if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , your aggregation should be like this :

```Json
    db.collectionName.aggregate([
 $group: {
        _id: {
            "userId": "$userId",
            "shareId": "$shareId"
        },
        value: {
            $max: "$value"
        },
        shareId: {
            $first: "$shareId"
        }
    }
])
```

> One thing to note, the table has tens and thousands of records so I do need it to be optimized if possible.
> here you need to build a convenient index :

```json
db.collectionName.createIndex(
  {"userId":-1,
  "shareId":-1});
```

Comment: I like this but i have a problem that i do not know the userId and shareId. I need to retrieve all the records in the table but where there is a duplicate userId/shareId combination only return the highest value

Comment: well, it wasn't clear in your question, I will edit please check

Comment: your answer looks clear to me thank you. i will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

```
res = await db.collection('exmaple').find({userId:userId,sharedId:shareId}).sort({value:-1}).toArray()
res[0] //// this is the
```

i wrote the code in `node.js`

`res[0]` is you expected result

`sort({value:-1})` sort value as highest to lowest